# DistributeDefinitions doesn't work as expected when used for table iterator bounds?

Tags: parallelization

I am new to parallelization in Mathematica, so this question may reflect some elementary confusion.  I am attempting to parallelize a rather complicated module which, as part of its internal operation, builds some tables.  I ran into some mysterious-looking errors, and the code doesn't work.  It turns out that the errors occur even when I try to run some very simple code:

```
K=3;
DistributeDefinitions[K];
ParallelEvaluate[Table[0, {i, 1, K}]]
```

I am using 2 parallel kernels, so I would expect this to generate the result

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

It actually does generate this result but it also generates errors:

```
(kernel 1) Table::iterb: Iterator {i,1,K} does not have appropriate bounds.
(kernel 2) Table::iterb: Iterator {i,1,K} does not have appropriate bounds.
```

I suppose that this means the parallel kernels are returning the command unevaluated, and then it's being evaluated by the master kernel before the output is printed.  What's going on -- how can I get the parallel kernels to use the value of K?

I am using Mathematica 8.0.4.0.  Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that capital-K is a reserved word.

```
?K
```

> K is a default generic name for a summation index in a symbolic sum.

Other single-character variables to avoid are:

```
C, D, E, I, N, O
```

Generally, you should avoid using variables that start with a capital character. It is not forbidden, but starting with a lowercase character will prevent you from colliding with built-in definitions that all start with a uppercase character.

Comment: Oh, fantastic, thank you!  I'll change the name.  It's funny:  if I try to assign a value to C, D, E, I, N, or O, I get an immediate complaint that the symbol is protected.  On the other hand Mathematica is perfectly happy to let me use K, and indeed I have been using it for quite some time; everything works fine AS LONG AS I don't try to distribute it to some other parallel kernels!

Comment: @AndrewNeitzke `K` is the only one that doesn't have the attribute `Protected`, which is why it lets you assign a value to it. Not knowing that `K` is built-in can bite you at times (and be hard to spot if you didn't know). See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/QinIGNetTkQ/discussion) for an example